# R: How to get the p-value (for getting x < 2) for a population (modeled by a combination of three normal distributions)?

Tags: r, distribution, probability

Thanks to the wonderful answers to my previous post, I used the procedures provided in the link below, to fit my data with three normal distributions:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10062/which-r-package-to-use-to-calculate-component-parameters-for-a-mixture-model

After fitting my data , the parameters for the three normal distributions are as follows:

```
      pi      mu sigma
1 0.5552 -0.4868 2.044
2 0.2739  8.3846 1.399
3 0.1709 12.5317 1.036
```

To check the agreements between my data (x) and the model distribution (ee), I did the following steps:

```
e1 <- rnorm(5552, mean=-0.4868, sd=2.044)
e2 <- rnorm(2739, mean=8.3846, sd=1.399)
e3 <- rnorm(1709, mean=12.5317, sd=1.036)
ee <- c(e1,e2,e3)
qqplot(x, ee)
```

I got the qqplot as follows: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/3favy.png)

It seems not bad, so, I want to calculate the p-value of obtaining a value equal to or less than 2.0 for this model population.  Could  you mind to teach me how to calculate this p-value using R?

The density plot of the model population ee is attached herein (https://i.stack.imgur.com/pExhF.png).

Comment: These type of questions you should ask on http://www.crossvalidated.com

Comment: It's not really a stats question. It's just how to do something in R. Although exactly what isn't 100% clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to calculate the tail-area probability with something like.

```
> sum(ee <= 2) / length(ee)
> [1] 0.4936
```

Comment: That's the empirical p-value from the data. I think the poster wants to compute the value from the fitted three-normal mixture model.

Comment: I read it as `ee' being a simulated dataset from the fitted model. Therefore a tail-area approximation should be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your parameters are in a dataframe, `param` (and maybe this would work with matrix with named columns).

The individual contributions to the "left of 2":

```
> probs <- with(param, pi*pnorm(2, mu, sigma) )
> probs
[1] 4.930888e-01 6.883473e-07 2.409615e-25
```

The total:

```
> prob <- with(param, sum(pi*pnorm(2, mu, sigma)) )
> prob
[1] 0.4930895
```

Just looking that the output you would guess that almost all of the contribution would be from the first component, since the means of hte other two are far to the right. The value of the first contribution is dominated by the pi(proportion) estimate since most of its mass is to the "left of 2".